# Shortest path visiting all 1s in a binary matrix (when visiting 0s is allowed)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given a matrix of n rows m columns
0<=n , m <=30
a non-zero value suggest we have to visit that node where as zero value suggest that we may or may not visit that node. All we have to do is visit all the non-zero value nodes and calculate the minimum distance required to complete this task. You can start from anywhere and you can only move horizontally or vertically in any direction. While moving from one node to another adjacent node distance travelled is counted as 1.
for example

```
n=3 and m=4
1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
soln: 5
The answer is 5 because, I will start from position(0 based indexing) 
(0,0)->(0,1)->(1,1)->(1,2)->(1,3)->(2,3)
n=3 and m=6
matrix is
1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
soln: 11
The answer is 5 because, I will start from position(0 based indexing) 
(2,5)->moving horizontally left to (2,0)->moving vertically up to(0,0)->moving horizontally right to (0,3) -> moving down to (1,3) and hence with this we will be visiting all the vertices
```

I have tried approaches like minimum spanning tree, breadth first search is not a good idea. Remember when you start from a point x,y and start moving you have to keep moving either horizontally or vertically until you haven't visited all the vertices at least once.

Comment: You should explain the examples you've posted. Why the solution is `5` or `11`? You can search what Breadth First Search (BFS) is and try applying to this problem. See if BFS is the right fit for this problem. Post the code you've written so far and issues you are facing with it. So, you need to add details or clarity to this post.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Sir, I have updated the question

Comment: Hey, thanks for being respectful. But no need to use sir/mam. Everyone is equal on this community.

Comment: Could you please cite the source of this problem please? I find this problem interesting.

Comment: It was asked in Goldman Sachs coding round for campus recruitment. Later posting this problem here I came to know that people were able to pass most of the test cases (10/12) using travelling salesman algorithm.

Comment: Right. `travelling salesman algorithm` is a `minimum cost Hamiltonian cycle` as I've already mentioned in my post. Its just that the salesman has to come back to his/her city but we don't have any such condition. In our case, how to connect components is another thing we have to take care of which I've mentioned in the post. Unlike in TSP, we are allowed to visit a vertex more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be hard (pun intended) than I thought from the initial reading of it. This looks to me like a **minimum cost Hamiltonian path** - **You have to visit every vertex of an undirected graph with minimum total cost.**

Suggested reading:

1. [The Minimum Flow Cost Hamiltonian Cycle Problem](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X15000499)
2. [How to solve the Shortest Hamiltonian Path problem on Sparse Graphs?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39694/how-to-solve-the-shortest-hamiltonian-path-problem-on-sparse-graphs)

I'll let you know if I can think of a relatively easier solution.

---

The second example you gave is

```
1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
```

The above can be translated to

[image]

[image]

**Forming a graph from given matrix:**

Treat every `1` as a node in a graph and there is an edge between adjacent vertices.

How to connect components?

Say C1 and C2 are two components. Find a pair <v1, v2> of vertices such that v1 belongs to C1, v2 belongs to C2 and distance between v1 & v2 is the least among all possible <v1, v2> pairs. How to find such pair? I'll leave that as an exercise. Try it out. If unable to do it, let me know.

**Compressing an edge:**

With some more efforts you can "compress" the edges in the graph. By "compress" I mean all the chains could be represented as one node. I have tried to represent what a chain means in the images above with help of colors respectively. Compression is not necessary though a good optimization.

If a vertex is connected to more than two vertices, don't include it in compression, for example the yellow node shown above. Notice that yellow node is connected to blue 1 because of component connection we discussed above.

---

If you are working with `0<=n, m <=30` constraint, you might not need to necessarily form a graph and compress it. As you say this question was asked during campus placement coding round, just try to work with the input matrix, submit and check if time limit exceeds. But during a face-to-face discussion, it might be expected to optimize by some means for example compression of edges is one optimization I could come up that could be helpful if graph contains chains or if number of `1`s are less as compared to number of `0`s - sparse matrix.

---

Comment: Please provide a coherent, consistent way to translate the binary matrix input to the graph your solution would have us work on.

Comment: Please provide a consistent method by which you are connecting a component of connected 1s to other components of connected 1s. Your current illustration seems to make an assumption about such connections without stating a method for it, which we would need in order to evaluate this answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן: As I was writing this solution, I was running through some steps in my mind. Your clarifying questions made me bring it in writing. Thanks. Let me know if any more suggestions. I was hoping for a better solution without going for a hard solution hence I didn't initially give out a full blown solution with a hope that someone posts an easier solution. But now OP has also hinted that it was TSP, I think we were on the right track from the beginning.